# Where to report build related issues of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, build

I'm building eclipse-platform-parent git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git and I'd like to file an enhancement request of the help of the bootstrap/boostrap.sh script. Where can I do this (I didn't find an appropreate category at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi)?

Answer (score 0):

The bugzilla category for the Eclipse Platform build is [Eclipse "Platform"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform), component "Releng".